# Hypotenuse of triangle Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, hypotenuse

Okay, pretty sure I got my formula right... don't think I quite understand how to call on methods, howcome mine isn't working?

```
    fun main() {
    println("Enter Width of the triangle")
    readln()
    println("Enter Height of the triangle")
    ComputeMethods().hypotenuse(readln().toDouble())
}

 class ComputeMethods(){
fun hypotenuse(width: Int, height: Int) {
    val triangle = width.toDouble().pow(2) + height.toDouble().pow(2)
    val formula = "$triangle"
    println(formula)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific about what's not working?

Comment: You are only passing one parameter to the function instead of two. You should probably store the result of the first `readln()` call in a variable and pass it to the function call as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Gilli, [Here is the working code example for triangle formula](https://pl.kotl.in/mq-8jgVRy), You have to pass input arguments in space separated format (2.0 3.0), You can interact with the link given https://pl.kotl.in/mq-8jgVRy in order to run the program on kotlin playground.

```
import kotlin.math.pow

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Enter Width of the triangle")
    val width = args[0].toDouble()
    println("Enter Height of the triangle")
    val height = args[1].toDouble()
    ComputeMethods().hypotenuse(width, height)
}

class ComputeMethods(){
fun hypotenuse(width: Double, height: Double) {
    val triangle = width.pow(2) + height.pow(2)
    val formula = "$triangle"
    println(formula)
    }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate that mate, got mine working. I had the logic all wrong! I get it now... think I need to take a step away from the computer HAHA! Need a break.

Answer (score 2):

Your `hypotenuse` function has two arguments of type `Int`. You are only giving it one, and also of the wrong type (`Double`). Also, the result of your first `readln` is not stored anywhere. To solve it you can do:

```
fun main() {
    println("Enter Width of the triangle")
    val width: Int = readln().toInt()
    println("Enter Height of the triangle")
    val height: Int = readln().toInt()
    ComputeMethods().hypotenuse(width, height)
}
```

PS: to get the hypotenuse you would also need to take the square root of that result